# How to use Apollo's Graphql HOC to pass a query function as a prop?

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I've been able to pass a mutation to a component using graphqls HOC, but was wondering how I can do the same for a query?

This is how I'd do it for a mutation:

```
import { gql, graphql } from 'react-apollo'

const updateAccountInfoConfig = {
  props: ({ mutate }) => ({
    updateAccountInfo: MutationInput => mutate({ variables: { input: MutationInput } }),
  })
};

const UPDATE_ACCOUNT_INFO = gql`
  mutation UpdateAccountInfo($input: UpdateAccountInfoInput!) {
    updateAccountInfo(input: $input) {
      result {
        didSucceed
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const UpdateAccountInfoButton = graphql(
  UPDATE_ACCOUNT_INFO,
  updateAccountInfoConfig
)(ActionButton);
```

It'd give me access to the `updateAccountInfo` function from the props of the `ActionButton` component. How can I do the same for a query? I can't seem to find it in the documentation.

EDIT - I found a workaround which is to run the query on render and then pass the refetch function to props. This isn't ideal because I'll always have that initial query on render, which I don’t want. Is there a way to skip the initial request but still have access to the refetch function?

This is what my config looks like:

```
const getAccountInfoConfig = {
  options: () => ({
    variables: { input: [''] },
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
  }),
  props: ({ data }) => {
    return {
      getAccountInfo: data.refetch
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2/api/react-hoc/#configskip

Comment: @xadm please could you expand on this? I’m not sure I understand how config skip can help me here.

Comment: if not run on init then on some condition, skip is for conditional query running

Comment: @xadm I don’t want the query to ever run though, unless I manually run it within my component. If I use skip, it looks like it won’t pass the refetch function to props since data.refetch will be undefined

Comment: HOCs are limited [and deprecated] - skip can be changed by prop (externally), you have to wrap it into another HOC with some state and pass setter (HOC hell) .... why HOCs? use `useLazyQuery`

Comment: @xadm I’m currently limited to Apollo client V1 so this is my only option. I’ll be on V3 in a few months but for now I need a solution to this.

Comment: AFAIK you can use both (HOCs and hooks) at least in v.2 (and probably in v.3, too)